# data tibble empties on shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am having trouble sending a tibble loaded from a user file to a plotting function. It seems that the table is indeed read and modified properly, but when I ask another function to use it for plotting the entries are missing.

on the Shiny server I have the following:

```
myData <- reactive({
    if (is.null(inFile())) {
        return(NULL)
    } else {
        
        tmp_table = read_csv(inFile()$datapath[1])
        # tmp_table = read_csv('Fazael_grain_size.csv')
        
        big_table=tmp_table
        
        # modify the factor columns into factors
        big_table$sample_name <- factor(big_table$sample_name)
        big_table$site <- factor(big_table$site)
        big_table$fraction <- factor(big_table$fraction)
        
        # remove NA rows
        big_table=big_table[!is.na(big_table$sample_name),]
        
        # make sure the table was loaded correctly
       output$table <- renderTable((big_table))
        
        return(big_table)
    }
})
```

[a screenshot showing the proper loading of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw3d2.png)

then I want to use this table for plotting, so I have the following chunk:

```
myPlot <- function(){

    # make sure the data exists

    req(myData())
    
    big_table=myData()
   
   # checking the tibble was properly sent to the plotting function
   output$table <- renderTable(big_table)
    
    # filter the data based on user selection
    big_table = filter(big_table,sample_name %in% input$selected_sample_name)
    big_table = filter(big_table,site %in% input$selected_site)
    big_table = filter(big_table,fraction %in% input$fraction)

    p =  big_table %>% 
        ggplot(aes_string(x=colnames(big_table)[4],y=colnames(big_table)[4])) +
        geom_point()

    if (!(input$color_variable %in% c("none"))) {
    p = p +
        geom_point(aes_string(color=input$color_variable))
    }
    
    p

}
```

for some reason the plot remains empty, and after some debugging I found out that the tibble is forwarded empty to it. any answers?

[a screenshot demonstrating that the entries in the table are not forwarded into the plotting function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYsjZ.png)

and indeed, the plot doesn't show up:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    myPlot()
})
```

[no plot appears on the plotting area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dobt2.png)

Answer (score 0):

solved. there was a small bug in the filter function:

should have been:
big_table = filter(big_table,fraction %in% input$selected_fraction)